# How to implement dblclick event on iPad

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad

I have a marquee planner that I've created for a client, and it basically consists of marquees and furniture that can be clicked and will be placed on a canvas to be dragged around. My major issue was getting it working correctly on touch devices, specifically iPad, and I got around the dragging by using touch punch, but the one thing I cannot get to work is the double click which is required to remove the element from the canvas.

Here is the planner: https://southwestmarquees.co.uk/newsite/marquee-planner/

If you open up the Furniture tab, click on a table and then double click that icon that appears it will remove it. The code I use is as follows:

```
$('.' + newItemClass).on('dblclick', function () {
    // remove any table planner data that may have been added.
    var existing_item_id = $(this).find('.add-guests').attr('data-item-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/newsite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            action: 'remove_table_planner_data',
            item_id: existing_item_id,
            plan_id: $('#plan-id').val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });

    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Just to explain, the action `remove_table_planner_data` just removes any existing data already saved for the table. I use visibility so that none of the other items already on the canvas are affected (I found that other elements jumped around if I used `remove()`)

I tried implementing a suggestion made on [this page](http://appcropolis.com/blog/howto/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads/) and even though it recognises it as an iOS device, I cannot get the code to work when I double tap the screen.

Any help on this is much appreciated as it's important that this planner works 100% correctly on iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a stand-alone HTML file with all the code. With only a jQuery dependency. I've tested it on an iPad through codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ModZyK

Code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- I added this meta tag to make sure the page doesn't try to zoom when double tapping on iPad -->
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var timer;
      // wait time between clicks
      var wait_ms = 200;
      // handler for the 1st click which adds the bind for the 2nd click
      first_click_handler = function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);

        $(this).bind('click', second_click_handler);
        timer = setTimeout((function() {
          // unbinding the second click if the user doesn't click within the wait_time, 200ms in this case
          $('.planner-board img').unbind('click', second_click_handler);
        }), wait_ms);
      }
      // handler for the second click, which is only removing the image
      second_click_handler = function() {
        $(this).remove();
      }

      $('.planner-board img').bind('click', first_click_handler);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="planner-board">
    <!-- ducks, why not -->
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gianni-polito/colobrush/256/software-duck-icon.png">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/martin-berube/animal/256/duck-icon.png">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried loading it up on my iPad, but after double clicking the images, nothing happens - am I missing something? I've tried several times.

Comment: Are you trying with the codepen link? Try experimenting with the *wait_ms* variable, higher value for a slower double tap.

Comment: Actually - I just tried it on my colleague's iPhone and it works - I'm guessing it must be a iOS version specific issue....let me try updating my iPad

Comment: It could be the double tap speed, play around with it, see what fits you best.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an outdated iOS issue - I'm currently upgrading the company iPad - it's not been used in a while so I'm guessing it's way out of date! I will report back when done. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I just checked and was testing on an iPad with iOS v10.3.1. The older iPads I have here are out of battery, can't help you there. It did work on an iPhone with iOS v9.3.5.

Comment: Have you been able to test it?

Comment: I haven't yet been able to implement it on my code as I've been away from work for a bit - but trying your example on my iPad pro worked fine, so it should be good, thank you!